# Replacing string regex python not working

Tags: python, regex

The program should get each of these punctuation characters replaced by that character surrounded by two spaces.

I tried this:

```
sent = re.sub('[!,\'!?.]',' \1 ', sent)
```

but it just printed some weird icon instead of those punctuation characters

This was done using python 3.

Comment: We need to see input, output and expected output to help you.

Comment: @ctwheels there is not much more to add, should be an answer!

Comment: The lesson here is to always use raw strings when working with regex

Answer (score 2):

The string "\1" was interpreted as ascii codepoint 1 \x01. To prevent this from happening, use the raw string r' \1'. Also, to use a back-reference, you should use parentheses. This is the result:

```
>>> sent = "!,\'!?."
>>> sent = re.sub(r'([!,\'!?.])',r' \1 ', sent)
>>> sent
" !  ,  '  !  ?  . "
```

Comment: Thanks that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

As per my original comment, your replacement is `\1` but you never created a capture group. Surround your regex in `()` as the following suggests. Also, you need to escape `\` or make it a raw string.

```
re.sub(r"([,'!?.])", r' \1 ', sent)
```

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolYurODWvRMFWQckjNScnXyE8vygnRVGJi6ugKDOvRKMoVa@4NEmjSEkjWkdd0V4vVlNJR6FIXSHGUEFdRwGkVVPz/38A)